# Outbound SSL connection in WLP

Tags: java, ssl, websphere, websphere-liberty

I have a spring security enabled web application which connects to LDAP using over SSL deployed on WLP. I have specified trustStore and password as below in `jvm.options` file

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path/to/keystore
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password
```

My `server.xml` looks as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="new server">
  <!-- Enable features -->
  <featureManager>
    <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
    <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
  </featureManager>

  <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint" host="*" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" />
  <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" location="/path/to/identity.jks" password="password" provider="SUN" />
  <webContainer deferServletLoad="false" />
  <application id="appId" location="/path/to/app.war" name="app" type="war" />
</server>
```

However I get the following exception

```
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I tried the same trust store with a standalone java program and it works. Any help is appreciated.

**NOTE:** If I include the trusted CA's in identity.jks it works

Thanks
Murali

Comment: Please run with "-Djavax.net.debug=all" to get full SSL debug logs, and paste with the question here.

Comment: Any reasons why you cannot use identity.jks to store that trusted CA?

Comment: I wanted it to be different because the server certificate is obtained from outside and CA certs are standard for all environments. But looks like I have to go with one keystore option.

Answer (score 1):

Your identity.jks is not recognized because it's not associated with the Http-Endpoint. There should be no need to use JSSE system properties as the truststore can be defined there too. You've not mentioned your wlp version. For 8.5 see here http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/rwlp_ssl.html

(*WebSphere Application Server Developer Tools for Eclipse* provide a user interface for editing server.xml)

Your server.xml should look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<server description="new server">
  <!-- Enable features -->
  <featureManager>
    <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
    <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
  </featureManager>

  <keyStore id="keyStore" location="/path/to/identity.jks" password="keyStorePassword" type="jks" />
  <keyStore id="trustStore" location="/path/to/truststore.jks" password="trustStorePassword" type="jks" />

  <sslDefault sslRef="defaultSSLConfig" />

  <ssl id="defaultSSLConfig" keyStoreRef="keyStore" serverKeyAlias="serverKeyAlias" trustStoreRef="trustStore" />

  <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint" host="*" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443">
    <sslOptions sslRef="defaultSSLConfig"></sslOptions>
  </httpEndpoint>
  <webContainer deferServletLoad="false" />
  <application id="appId" location="/path/to/app.war" name="app" type="war" />
</server>
```